# not found: value autoConstruct

Tags: scala, playframework, scalikejdbc

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]https://github.com/t2v/play2-auth/blob/46d2dafa883551afdf3cb87f771195b911816dca/sample/app/jp/t2v/lab/play2/auth/sample/Account.scala

のコードで、autoConstructが解決されないのですが、どうすればよいですか？

build.sbt

```
name := """bank"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc"        % "2.2.+",
  "com.h2database"  %  "h2"                 % "1.4.+",
  "ch.qos.logback"  %  "logback-classic"    % "1.1.+",
  "jp.t2v" %% "play2-auth"      % "0.13.2",
  "jp.t2v" %% "play2-auth-test" % "0.13.2" % "test",
  "com.github.t3hnar" %% "scala-bcrypt" % "2.4"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`autoConstruct` はマクロで実験的な機能なので、現時点(2.2.5)ではscalikejdbc本体とは別になっています。
具体的には
`"org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc-syntax-support-macro" % "バージョン"`
です。
その他、そのサンプルのプロジェクトで加えるべき依存は、このあたり

https://github.com/t2v/play2-auth/blob/46d2dafa883551afdf3cb87f771195b911816dca/project/Build.scala#L91-L97

などを参考にしてください。

Comment: なるほど。ありがとうございます。